# Postgres/pgadmin3 - Selecting all columns equal to true for a given row

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm not sure exactly how to go about doing this, but I have to select all columns in a given row in which the value is equal to the boolean TRUE.

i.e.

```
Columns: |  X   |  Y    |  Z   |  A   |
0        | TRUE | FALSE | TRUE | TRUE |
```

In this case, I would need an SQL statement that would return:

```
Columns: |  X   |  Z   |  A   |
0        | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE |
```

I'm doing this across a table whose size will not change (it's static essentially) with about 250 columns and 220 rows.

Eventually, I'm going to need a statement which returns the names of the columns where TRUE, basically:

```
0       |  X   |  Z   |  A   |
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT 1**

Based on Nicarus' solution below, I came up with the following:

```
WITH i (A, B, C)
AS (
SELECT attributes.A, B, C
FROM (attributes JOIN contexts ON attributes.A = contexts.A)
WHERE context_full_name = 'Print book'
),
i_sub AS (
SELECT 
    A,
    UNNEST(ARRAY['B', 'C']) 
        AS col_name,
    UNNEST(ARRAY[B, C]) 
        AS col_value
FROM i)
SELECT STRING_AGG(col_name, ',') AS true_col_names INTO temporary_table
FROM i_sub WHERE col_value = TRUE GROUP BY A;

SELECT * FROM temporary_table;
```

However, I am returned a result that is false with the final select statement...

I double-checked using:

```
SELECT *
FROM (attributes JOIN contexts ON attributes.attribute_id = contexts.attribute_id)
WHERE context_full_name = 'Print book';
```

And the column is definitely false...

Did I mess something up?

**EDIT 2**

So the query in EDIT 1 is trying to achieve the following; changing this:

```
Columns: |  X   |  Y    |  Z   |  A   |
0        | TRUE | FALSE | TRUE | TRUE |
1        | TRUE | TRUE  | TRUE | FALSE|
2        | FALSE| FALSE | TRUE | FALSE|
```

In this case, I would need an SQL statement that would return:

```
Columns: |  X   |  Z   |  A   |
0        | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE |
```

Instead, it is returning all columns with a true value anywhere:

```
Columns: |  X   |  Y    |  Z   |  A   |
0        | TRUE | TRUE  | TRUE | TRUE |
```

**MY IMPLEMENTATION**

This is my no means the most efficient, but it worked for what I was looking to accomplish:

```
SELECT attributes.attribute_id, context_full_name, A, B, C, D
INTO TEMP j
FROM (attributes JOIN contexts ON attributes.attribute_id = contexts.attribute_id)
WHERE contexts.context_full_name = 'Print book' LIMIT 1;

WITH i_sub AS (
    SELECT
        attribute_id,
        context_full_name,
        UNNEST(ARRAY[A, B, C, D]) AS col_value
    FROM j)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER () as rn, *
INTO TEMP temporary_table
FROM i_sub;

SELECT context_full_name, attribute_id, temporary_table.rn, temporary_table.col_value, attribute_titles.attribute_name_column, attribute_titles.attribute_names
INTO TEMP result
FROM
(temporary_table JOIN attribute_titles -- attribute titles is a table I created which lists the column headers in the same order as they are in the attributes table, so that the row number on the temporary_table equals the attribute_titles column "attribute_name_id".
ON temporary_table.rn = attribute_titles.attribute_name_id) WHERE col_value = TRUE;

SELECT * FROM result; -- This prints the list with the attribute_id, context_full_name, the column value where TRUE (to check to make sure it worked), the column names shown in attribute_titles, and the attribute names (plaintext versions). This table can be further manipulated as necessary.
```

Comment: Are the `TRUE` and `FALSE` values within the same column the same for all rows? Meaning, `X` is always `TRUE` or always `FALSE` for all rows?

Comment: No, they are not sorry. Although I am only ever using one row at a time, so I could create a temporary subtable with only one row? (That way they would be the same for all rows in the subtable?)

Comment: You don't select columns.  You select rows.  Columns from the matching rows then get projected.  So what that means in this case is that since each row could have a different mix of true/false column value combinations, each row would have a different structure in the result set.  That can't happen.  A result set is a table structure.  Rows by columns.  You can't have different columns for each row in the query's result set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% certain of your use case; however, you can return a "list" of the column names where their value is `TRUE`. This is only one way to do so.

Here I "un-pivot" the data, filter out any `FALSE` records, then concatenate the column names to return a single record per row. You may also decide to leave the data more normalized (not concatenating the column names)

```
WITH mytable (row_id,X,Y,Z,A) AS
(
VALUES
    (1,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE),
    (2,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE),
    (3,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE)
),

mycte AS
(
SELECT
    row_id,
    UNNEST(ARRAY['X','Y','Z','A']) AS col_name,
    UNNEST(ARRAY[X,Y,Z,A]) AS col_value
FROM
    mytable
)

SELECT
    row_id,
    STRING_AGG(col_name,'|') AS true_col_names
FROM
    mycte
WHERE
    col_value
GROUP BY
    row_id;
```

---

You state you are still having issues, though I am not clear on what they are.

I used your query (with my test data) and I get this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temporary_table;

WITH i (A,B,C) AS
(
VALUES
    (TRUE,TRUE,FALSE),
    (FALSE,TRUE,FALSE),
    (TRUE,TRUE,TRUE)
),

i_sub AS (
SELECT 
    A,
    UNNEST(ARRAY['B', 'C']) 
        AS col_name,
    UNNEST(ARRAY[B, C]) 
        AS col_value
FROM i)

SELECT
    STRING_AGG(col_name, ',') AS true_col_names,
    STRING_AGG(DISTINCT col_name, ',') AS true_col_names_unique --only unique col_names
INTO
    temporary_table
FROM
    i_sub
WHERE
    col_value;

SELECT * FROM temporary_table;
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Currently working on using this solution, but can I pass a SELECT statement for a row instead of a VALUES clause as specified in the beginning of your answer?

Comment: Yes, you can replace VALUES... with your own SELECT

Comment: @user3684314 Simpler a bit using [hstore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html) extension: `... select akeys(hstore(mytable) - hstore('x=>f,y=>f,z=>f,a=>f')) from mytable;`

Comment: @Nicarus I updated the question with an implementation of your code that I tried (I replaced the column names for simplicity's sake, but everything else is the same). I'm returning some columns which are false.

Comment: @user3684314 - Can you confirm the data type of the columns B, C, etc. are truly `BOOLEAN` and not `TEXT`?

Comment: Confirmed, they are boolean as specified in the table creation and the nested SELECT returns them as booleans; further the ARRAY function returns an array of boolean values (having any other data type there causes an error).

Comment: If you run this `SELECT DISTINCT col_value FROM i_sub WHERE col_value;` What returns? Should only be `TRUE`

Comment: OK... so I ran `SELECT col_name FROM i_sub WHERE col_name = 'A'` and it returned 239 rows... So I think the issue is that it is passing in every single row, instead of just one...

Comment: If you only want one `col_name` *AND* only `FALSE` for the `col_value`, you need to change your `WHERE` clause to this: `WHERE col_name = 'A' AND col_value = TRUE`

Comment: I'm just confused as to why it's printing out the entire `attributes` table pivoted instead of the one row I passed in with my `SELECT` statement...

Comment: In your most recently posted query - why are you using a `GROUP BY` at all?

Comment: That...is a good point. I removed it, but am still getting the same result.

Comment: I'm not completely understanding - are you wanting to get the unique `col_names` only? That is the only issue I can see when I test your exact query

Comment: I think there might just be a misunderstanding here... I edited my question as well, but I think it might be related to the usage of the `SELECT` query... You've been amazingly helpful, I'm sorry for the confusion

Comment: I selected your answer as correct because it helped me find the answer that I was looking for (which I will add to the question as an edit just in case anyone is running into similar issues). Thank you so much for your help @Nicarus!